# NSView-based table view with auto layout grows, but does not shrink rows

Tags: cocoa, autolayout, nstableview, appkit, nstableviewcell

I have a NSTableView in view-based mode (not cell-based) with **usesAutomaticRowHeights=YES**. The rows have dynamic height that might change at any time. This setup successfully grows table view rows (row content is never clipped), but table view rows don't shrink to the intrinsic row view height when rows get shorter. Calling noteHeightOfRowsWithIndexesChanged: on the table view after layout does not seem to fix the problem, my tableView:heightOfRow: is also not called again after noteHeightOfRowsWithIndexesChanged:.

Is there anything I have missed/isn't documented about using auto layout in NSView-based tableviews with variable row height? After all, growing rows always works without any additional code, they just do not shrink on their own.

```
NSTableView* tv = [[NSTableView alloc] init];

[tv setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[tv setUsesAutomaticRowHeights:YES];     // Use auto layout for row height

NSTableColumn* column = [[NSTableColumn alloc] init];
[tv addTableColumn:column];

// Set table view data source and delegate, rows are then loaded...
```

Comment: Post a [mre] please.

Comment: How do you change the height of the cells?

Comment: Autolayout constraints within the row content views. However, the cell height only increases this way, never shrinks

Comment: What makes the cells expand and shrink? How can we reproduce the issue?

Comment: There is nothing else happening, just a NSView displayed in a table view cell. But the auto layout enabled tabled view just increases row height and does not want to shrink it, even if the intrinsic height of the content row view is less tall than the table view row view

Comment: I tried your code but I don't see any isues. Post a [mre] please.

Comment: There is nothing more to it, the only important part is `setUsesAutomaticRowHeights:YES`. As-is, the table view does never shrink table view rows once they have grown based on intrinsic content size, even when breaking autolayout constraints .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debugging the default table view layout for a long time, I finally found the issue. The table view row views come with some autoresizingmask settings that interfere with content, when using autolayout for the row content views. You need to set the *row view's* `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `NO`. This can be achieved for a view-based NSTableView using the delegate method `tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView didAddRowView:(NSTableRowView *)rowView forRow:(NSInteger)row`:

```
- (void)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView didAddRowView:(NSTableRowView *)rowView forRow:(NSInteger)row
{   
    // Remember that rowView != row content view!
    [rowView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];   // Disable constraints interfering with row view content
}
```

Interestingly, this does not seem to be an issue if content does not shrink past the initial row height or maximum row height it has grown to, due to dynamic height increases.